# How to enable installation of monero gui, blocked by windows 10?

Tags: windows, installation

I download just now

```
monero-gui-install-win-x64-v0.14.0.0.exe
```

Windows 10 is blocking it because it is affected by a virus. Of course, It is not possible. I just downloaded from official link.

I disabled avast antivirus.

I disabled smart screen

I right-clicked on file name and removed the block unchecking the 'block' option.

Any way, I still get alert from Windows 10. What's to quit/kill/configure to be able to run monero gui installer?

> This question is not a duplicate of the linked one, because I applied ALL and more than suggested and NOTHING changes.

Comment: Please see the guide I linked.

Comment: Please note that I did all of what you said in your guide, so please, this is not a duplicated question because your answer is not usefull for mine!

Comment: Possibly Windows Defenders is still acting as active AV. Have you checked that?

Comment: How can I check if is still active as active AV? It show me that my AV is Avasta

Comment: Opening Windows Defender should show the status. You could try whitelisting the GUI both in Windows Defender and Avasta I guess.